# sqlite3 recursive aggregation of data

Tags: recursion, sqlite, aggregate

This may be a kind of the Knapsack problem.
I need to traverse a data table, group it by a column, choosing ones with better time.
Then repeat the previous step until a limit given by column CAPACITY is not reached.

**This is the demo scenario:**

```sql
create table if not exists data( vid num, size num, epid num, sid num, capacity num, dt );
    delete from data;
    insert into data(vid,size,epid,sid,capacity,dt)
    values
        (0,20,1,1,50,1100), -- 2nd choice
        (0,20,1,1,50,1000), -- 1st choice
        (0,20,1,1,50,1200), -- last choice excluded because out of capacity
        (1,20,2,2,50,1100), -- 2nd choice
        (1,20,2,2,50,1000), -- 1st choice
        (1,20,2,2,50,1200); -- last choice excluded because out of capacity
```

**This is the non recursive solution:**

```sql
with best0 as (
    select a.rowid as tid,a.vid,a.sid,a.size,a.dt,a.capacity-a.size as remains,0 as level 
    from data a 
    group by a.sid 
    having min(a.dt)
    ),
best1 as (
    select a.tid,a.vid,a.sid,a.size,a.dt,a.remains, a.level 
    from (
        select 
            a.rowid as tid,a.sid,a.vid,a.size,a.capacity,a.dt,b.remains-a.size as remains,
            b.level+1 as level 
        from data a 
        join best0 b on b.sid=a.sid -- and b.level=a.level-1
        where not a.rowid in (select tid from best0) 
          and b.remains-a.size>0
        ) a group by a.sid having min(a.dt)
    ),
best2 as (
    select a.tid,a.vid,a.sid,a.size,a.dt,a.remains, a.level 
    from (
        select 
            a.rowid as tid,a.sid,a.vid,a.size,a.capacity,a.dt,b.remains-a.size as remains,
            b.level+1 as level 
        from data a 
        join best1 b on b.sid=a.sid -- and b.level=a.level-1
        where not a.rowid in (select tid from best0 union all select tid from best1) 
          and b.remains-a.size>0
        ) a group by a.sid having min(a.dt)
    )
select * from best0
union all
select * from best1
union all
select * from best2
```

And this the result:

```
tid | vid | sid | size | Dtime | capacity | group_level
--- | --- | --- | ---- | ----- | -------- | -----------
2   | 0   | 1   | 20   | 1000  | 30       | 0
5   | 1   | 2   | 20   | 1000  | 30       | 0
1   | 0   | 1   | 20   | 1100  | 10       | 1
4   | 1   | 2   | 20   | 1100  | 10       | 1
```

This is the recursive version that give error: "recursive reference in a subquery: best"

```sql
with recursive best(tid,vid,sid,size,dt,remains,level) 
as (
    select a.rowid as tid,a.vid,a.sid,a.size,a.dt,a.capacity-a.size as remains,0 as level 
    from data a 
    group by a.sid 
    having min(a.dt)

    union all

    select a.tid,a.vid,a.sid,a.size,a.dt,a.remains, a.level 
    from (
        select 
            a.rowid as tid,a.sid,a.vid,a.size,a.dt,b.remains-a.size as remains,
            b.level+1 as level 
        from data a 
        join best b on b.sid=a.sid -- and b.level=a.level-1
        where not a.rowid in (select tid from best) and b.remains-a.size>0
        ) a group by a.sid having min(a.dt)
    )
select * from best
```

I tried differents solutions even using a loop counter but everyone give the same error.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte) says that "the recursive table must appear exactly once in the FROM clause of the recursive-select and must not appear anywhere else in either the initial-select or the recursive-select, including subqueries."

Comment: Maybe use UNION instead of UNION ALL to ignore duplicates?

Comment: Yes, i know. I'm searching a way to write the recursion (if it is).
There are no duplicates. Data used in the demo are simplified.